# How can I change Django's project database name running on MAMP?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, mamp, django-settings

So, I have a running project that uses a MySQL database with a MAMP local server but for compliance issues I need to change the database name. So I changed it in MAMP and I changed it in settings.py as seen bellow:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'prototipodb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'palapa',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'palapa',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',  # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

I thought that with these changes everything would keep running smoothly, but I got the following error on my server:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/palapa2/projects/prototipo_tesis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
>       self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
>     File "/Users/palapa2/projects/prototipo_tesis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
>       num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
>     File "/Users/palapa2/projects/prototipo_tesis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
>       connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
>     File "/Users/palapa2/projects/prototipo_tesis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
>       db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
>     File "/Users/palapa2/projects/prototipo_tesis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 415, in get_server_version
>       self.cursor().close()
>     File "/Users/palapa2/projects/prototipo_tesis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/**init**.py", line 306, in cursor
>       cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
>     File "/Users/palapa2/projects/prototipo_tesis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
>       self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
>     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 81, in Connect
>     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in **init**
>   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'prototipodb'")

I would appreciate if you can help me with this problem. One of the things I've been thinking about doing is run `syncbd` command to rebuild the connection, but if there is a better solution to this I would gladly consider it.

Comment: did you changed `'NAME': 'prototipodb',` to the correct database name, since it didn't looks like you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this on my mac and it works fine. I copied the DB and changed the name in `settings.py`. Then I gave my user access to the new DB.`

Did you give user `palapa` access to the new DB?

Did you flush privileges?

Did you restart Django server?

Comment: I was renaming the database on MAMP dashboard. Now I copied it and it worked just fine! Thanks!!!!